# Having a problem calling the function AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput through python library

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to process a .wav file with the Azure Cognitive Speech Service. I am using the script below. I get an exception that says "type object 'AudioConfig' has no attribute 'FromWavFileInput'" when I try to setup the wav file by calling [AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig.fromwavfileinput). The documentation says the function exists, at least in the .net library. Does FromWaveFileInput exist for the [cognitiveservices-speech python library](https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/)? How can I process an audio file with python?

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

speechKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
service_region = 'eastus2'

#### # Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
#### # Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speechKey, region=service_region)

audioInput = speechsdk.AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput('RainSpain.wav')

#### # Creates a recognizer with the given settings
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_input=audioInput)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed as you said. I searched for the keywords `AudioConfig` & `FromWavFileInput` on GitHub repo [`Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk), there is not any Python codes about it except for Java, C#, and [C++](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/3131ab75577116fe9359242d6d86321808601e19/samples/cpp/windows/console/samples/speech_recognition_samples.cpp#L116).

So per my experience, there are two workaround ways to do it.

1. Wrap the C++ codes as a [Python extension module](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html), or communicate with C++/Java codes.
2. Directly using [Speech service REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-apis) with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), it's simple for Python and Azure Speech Service.

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm

```py
audio_filename = "something.wav"
audio_input =speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_filename)
```